# How to check whether json object has some property

Tags: c#, json

In `Java` there is a nice method `has` that makes it possible to check whether a json object contains a key or not. I use it like so:

```
JSONObject obj = ....; // <- got by some procedure
if(obj.has("some_key")){
    // do something
}
```

I could not find the same cool functionality in `newtonsoft.json` library for `C#`. So, I wonder what are the alternatives. Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204235/1037314)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just use obj["proprty_name"]. If the property doesn't exist, it returns null

```
if(obj["proprty_name"] != null){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try like this:

```
IDictionary<string, JToken> dict = x;
if (dict.ContainsKey("some_key"))
```

since `JSONObject` implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`. You can refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonobject.containskey(v=vs.95).aspx) for details

Comment: He's using `Newtonsoft.Json` not `System.Json`

Answer (score -2):

Use this JToken.ContainsKey()
This should work.

Comment: Class `JToken` has no such method ;) https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm