# Was a JSON property present on a ASP.NET Core WebAPI HttpPost

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have a Controller in a ASP.NET Core WebAPI. On a `HttpPost` I receive the body of the post via the `[FromBody]` referenced input variable.

For the purposes of this question, let's assume I'm expecting to receive the following JSON submission with `null` being a valid value.

```
{
    "start": null,
    "finish": "Far far away"
}
```

When submitted and `start` is not present the C# variable simply reflect a `null` for `start`.

How can I go about finding out if the `start` property was present or not in the `HttpPost`?

Comment: what is the data type of `start`?

Comment: use json.net, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216917/json-net-has-key-method

Comment: It is fair to assume `start` is of type string, the question would remain was it some other data type

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JObject` if you want more control over the payload. An example is:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/test")]
public IHttpActionResult Test(JObject item)
{
    //Check if start is included
    var data = item.ToObject<YourClass>();
    ...

}
```

With `[FromBody]` , deserialization happens on the fly, hence difficult to intercept the result.