# How to deserialize json objects to specific objects in Restsharp/Json.net on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, json.net, restsharp, json-deserialization

I am using Xamarin forms and fetching a list of JSON objects, which are of multiple `Types`. E.g.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public int Id;
}

class ClassA: BaseClass
{
    public string Name;
}

class ClassB: BaseClass
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth;
}
```

and so on..

When I fetch such objects (`ClassA`, `ClassB`, ...), I use the following line to deserialize them into the `BaseClass`

```
var response = await RestClient.PostTaskAsync<List<BaseClass>>(request);
```

And latter try to cast them into `ClassA` or `ClassB`, only to get `null` for all the `BaseClass` objects.
I simply expect a `List<BaseClass>` containing `ClassA`, `ClassB`... objects.

What am I missing here? Is there a setting/configuration for the Serializer , where I could pass the specific classes to get the specifically serialized?

Comment: The list knows nothing about the derived classes, only the base class. Review your design.

Comment: Agreed. Is there a way to specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this with a custom JsonConverter

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return (objectType == typeof(BaseClass));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (jo["identifyingField"].Value<string>() == "ExpectedValue")
            return jo.ToObject<ConcreteClass>(serializer);

        if (jo["identifyingField"].Value<string>() == "ExpentedValue2")
            return jo.ToObject<ConcreteClass2>(serializer);

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Luckily my objects had an identifying field in them which makes things easier...

If all of your concrete classes have unique fields to them, you can simply check `jo["identifyingField"] != null`

[json.net has key method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216917/json-net-has-key-method)

And to use your new CustomConverter...

```
var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
JsonConverter[] converters = { new CustomConverter() };
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeObject>(content, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = converters});
```

Comment: So was I, although it was a slightly different implementation since the `ToObject<>()` didn't really work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling it to deserialize the response to a list of BaseClass objects... that's exactly what it's returning to you.  I'm not entirely sure how you would do a conditional deserialization.  An approach I have used in the past is to have a PostTaskResponse object that defines all the possible properties you would have, then cast those to your expected result.

Comment: Could you post a snippet?